# How to identify duplicates in 2 columns of first and last name in 2 separate csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have two separate csv files with different and duplicate names, I would like to remove the duplicate names and export them into a csv identifying only duplicates.

csv_file1:

```
first_name, last_name
lucas, micker
kyle, smith
mark, davis 
danny, green
myles, cook
```

csv_file2:

```
first_name, last_name
corey, mintzer 
lucas, erin
mark, davis 
danny, green 
myles, turner
```

expected output:

```
first_name, last_name
mark, davis
danny, green
```

Here is my code which isnt working. Im not good with the panda library and im sure there are other ways to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
c = pd.merge(a, b, how='inner', on=['first_name', 'last_name'])
c.to_csv('remove_dup_.csv')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That *should* work, can you be more precise about what "isn't working"? Perhaps this is a leading/trailing whitespace issue or are you getting more duplicates in your output?

Comment: I agree with @ALollz that should work.

Answer (score 0):

This solves it for you:

**Data**

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['lucas', 'micker'],
                ['kyle', 'smith'],
                ['mark', 'davis' ],
                ['danny', 'green'],
                ['myles', 'cook']], columns = ['first', 'last'])
b = pd.DataFrame([['corey', 'mintzer' ],
                ['lucas', 'erin'],
                ['mark', 'davis' ],
                ['danny', 'green' ],
                ['myles', 'turner']] , columns = ['first', 'last'])
```

or

```
a = pd.read_csv(path1)
b = pd.read_csv(path2)
for col in ['first', 'last']: # remove whitespace at end of strings
    a[col] = a[col].map(lambda x: x.lstrip().rstrip()) 
    b[col] = a[col].map(lambda x: x.lstrip().rstrip())
```

**Solution**

```
c = pd.concat([a,b], axis=0) # stack  dataframes
d = c[c.duplicated(keep='first')] # get duplicated rows
```

**Output**

```
print(d.to_string())
   first   last
7   mark  davis
8  danny  green
```

Comment: Both of my csv file contains hundreds of lines, how can I make it so it can take in the file path for "a" and "b"

Comment: Are there headers in those files?

Comment: There are headers in those files

Comment: Okay, I edited the files and also added a step for cleaning the strings, as you may have a problem with whitespace at the end of your strings

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, the problem is that you don't name the columns of your csv. By default pandas takes the first row of your csv as the column names.

Here is how you could modify your csv to make your code work:

csv_file1:

```
first_name,last_name
lucas, micker
kyle, smith
mark, davis 
danny, green
myles, cook
```

csv_file2:

```
first_name,last_name
corey, mintzer 
lucas, erin
mark, davis 
danny, green 
myles, turner
```